# Connection pooling with SQL Express 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I want to create web site that's connect with SQL server express 2014.

I want to my system user to has his/her own connection, not share with others.

And I start testing with same user id and add "POOLING=FALSE" in my connection string, and write a testing program that open connection and never close the connection.

In SQL Server Profiler, server will login and assign a new SPID for that connection, but sometimes the connection closed unexpected.

I want to know what is going on here, and how can I create sql connection per login user and how can I set the life time of the connection when the connection is idle?

Thanks a lot!!!

```
Here is the result I got in Profiler:
....
Audit Login,SPID =305
Audit Login,SPID =306
Audit Login,SPID =307
Audit Login,SPID =308
Audit Logout,SPID =171
Audit Logout,SPID =188
Audit Logout,SPID =165
...
Audit Login,.... SPID =171.... (Reuse the released SPID)
```

Best Regards,

Mark Yip

---

Thanks for replying !

I want to keep every login user a separate connection is use for special purpose,

Here is my actual problem...

If there is a record , let say a student record.

In the past, I will check the time-stamp each time before update the record to prevent other user(s) modified the same record when you are editing, if the time-stamp is different, updates for the user is rejected due to the record is updated by others already. I don't know is it the best practice to do this.

Now, if I create a connection for all active login user...

If the user want to edit the record, I will use the assigned connection to - begin tran and update "locked by" column as the SPID of connection.

When other user want to edit this record,

I will run this query : select x,y,x, "lockedBy" from student with (nolock) where id = 1

if locked by is not empty, that's mean the record is editing by other connection, a message will show to user,

"Record is editing by others, please try again later!"

So am I going to a wrong direction to thinking about this problem?

Once again, Thank you very much!

Best Regards,

Mark

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please view my question agian~ I posted the details. Thanks

Comment: Your original approach to use the timestamp looks a lot like Optimistic Locking and it will most probably be easier to implement. Alternatively you could try to use application locks (`sp_getapplock` etc) to mark something as 'in use' rather than putting the SPID in the records. The problem will remain though that connections will get dropped accidentally, thus releasing the locks. I'm also not sure how many simultaneous connections your machine can handle. SQL can handle 32k I believe, but your OS might be much more limited thus making new connections beyond an arbitrary number impossible)

Comment: Hi deroby, thanks for replys, sp_getapplock seems cannot solve my problem. It just prevent store proc to run at the same time? If the user lost his connection, the SPID will be removed due to the transaction is not commited which is expected.